# Downloading file from online database using bash script

Tags: database, r, bash, curl, wget

I want to download some files from an online database, but it does not allow me to download all the files at once.  Instead it offers to download a file for a searched keyword.  Because I have more than 20000 keywords, it's not feasible for me.
For example, I want to download whole information about miRNA-mRNA interaction from [SarBase](http://starbase.sysu.edu.cn/index.php), but it does not offer an option to download all of them at once. 
I wonder, how can I download it by writing some scripts. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please give a URL to one of the databases you want to download.  I have no idea what mRNA is... :)

Comment: @Jess, this is the URL : http://starbase.sysu.edu.cn/mirMrna.php

Comment: please go to the database you want to download.  Right click the hyperlink and do "Copy URL".  That is the url I am interested in.  We can do this!  :D

Comment: Here's an example: **`http://www.mirbase.org/cgi-bin/get_seq.pl?acc=MI0000342`**, but I have no idea if that is what you are trying to download.

Comment: @BMW, Is there a way you can roll back your edit?  I provided the sample URL to the OP so they might know what to look for.  The OP has yet to privde the exact download URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a file called getdb.sh.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Download keywords in kw.txt."
for kw in $(cat kw.txt)
do
    curl http://www.mirbase.org/cgi-bin/get_seq.pl?acc=$kw > $kw.txt
done
```

Create another file called kw.txt:

```
MI0000342
MI0000343
MI0000344
```

Then run this

```
$ chmod +x getdb.sh
$ ./getdb.sh

Download keywords in kw.txt.

$ ls -1 *.txt
kw.txt
MI0000342.txt
MI0000343.txt
MI0000344.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

another way

```
cat kw.txt |xargs -i curl -o {}.txt http://www.mirbase.org/cgi-bin/get_seq.pl?acc={}
```